# Passing parameters to jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating a basic HTML form that will send values to a `.jsp` page hosted on another domain. As I am not familiar with `.jsp`, I don't know how it takes parameters,

When I send this URL http://otherdomain.com/login.jsp?username=abc&password=def

It gives me output, but some username contains symbols like '+', etc.

So when trying this URL:

http://otherdomain.com/login.jsp?username=+abc&password=def

It gives me an invalid username or password error.

Please if anyone knows the solution, help me!

Comment: does the username/password contains spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can try url encode for the values you are passing to the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode parameter using javascript like this :

```
encodeURIComponent("ab+c")
```

and decode parameter in server side :

```
username = URLDecoder.decode(username)
```

Generally speaking, login.jsp should be receive request with http post method, you can try to use post method to send parameters to jsp, that's can be avoided encode parameter problem.

Comment: i will post jsp code here if i familed to try, i am not familiar with it, i will try if it works...........

Comment: this is how it gets the parameter jsp file String password = authentication.san(request.getParameter("password") ) ;

Comment: password = request.getParameter("password");password = URLDecoder.decode(password )